# Convert one byte to signed byte or int

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte, signed

`oxfc` is negative but I have it as a `byte` and its value is **252**, is there any way to convert it to signed `byte` or `int`?

I found this method:

```
(BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] { 0, 0xfc }, 0) / 256).ToString()
```

But is there any better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply cast it:

```
byte b = 0xfc;
sbyte s = unchecked((sbyte)b);
```

Comment: He said "oxfc is negative" so I don't think a negative value can be casted to a byte. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Transcendent: He says he has 0xFC already in a byte (its value is 252) and wants it interpreted in two's complement (-4) and saved to a signed varianle.

Comment: So that's a positive value in that case, I don't understand why he mentioned that 0xfc is a negative value.

Comment: @Transcendent: It is negative according to a two's complement interpretation.  (actually, also according to one's complement and signed-magnitude)